# Cassandra multi-DC: need write on LOCAL and read from any DC

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

My project requirement goes like this. We use a multi-data center (DC) cassandra cluster. During write on to the cluster, I want only LOCAL DC to perform writes on its nodes as we are already routing the write requests to the desired DC only based on the source from where write is initiated. So, I want only LOCAL DC to process the write and no other DC to perform the writes on its nodes. But later on by virtue of replication among nodes across DCs, I want the written data to be replicated across DCs. Is this replication across DCs possible when I am restricting the write to only one DC in the first place. I thought of using DCAwareRoundRobin policy for this. If I do not open connections to REMOTE hosts lying in different DCs during my write operation, is data replication possible amongst DCs later on. Why I definitely need replicas of data in all DCs is because during data read from cluster, we want the data to be read from any DC the read request falls on, not necessarily the LOCAL one.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's definitely possible. Consistency levels with prefix "LOCAL_" allow to write data to single data center and asynchronously replicate it to other. But in this case only eventual consistency is guaranteed, that means that the written data doesn't appear immediately in other data centers because of asynchronous replication. If you need strong consistency between data centers that you should use consistency levels with prefix "EACH", but it's significantly affects latency.

If you need strong consistency for write request in single data center the following rule should be satisfied (nodes_written + nodes_read) > number_of_replicas, for example if you have 3 replicas in each data center, both read and write requests should be performed with LOCAL_QUORUM consistency level(2 + 2 > 3). If eventual consistency is sufficient LOCAL_ONE can be used.

[There is](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/multi-datacenter-replication) similar case in "Geographical Location Scenario" section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nikita. One more clarification. I use LOCAL_QUORUM for read consistency in my multi-DC cluster with three DCs - DC1, DC2, DC3 with three nodes in each DC with replication factor of 3. During read, let us assume request first lands on a node in DC1. This node has failed and 2nd node in DC1 is contacted and so on and assume all nodes in DC1 have failed. Then will the cluster look to either DC2 or DC3 to satisfy the LOCAL_QUORUM, i.e., look for acknowledgement of two consistent reads from either one of the DCs (DC2 or DC3) and if yes, will the read be considered successful?

Comment: CQL query won't hit other data centers in case of LOCAL_QUORUM can't be succeed in local data center. However drivers implement such feature using DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy as you mentioned, but seems that it's [not recommended](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-local-quorum-should-stay-local-c174d555cc57). Also [this article](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-how-many-nodes-are-talked-to-with-quorum-also-should-i-use-it-98074e75d7d5) can be helpful for choosing of proper consistency level.